# In Service fabric what is the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT being used

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-service-fabric

Is there any place I can see what is the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT being used by Service fabric? This would help in figuring out if the correct configuration has been taken up.

Comment: Have you tried using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");` ? and then output this values somewhere like log, events, api

Answer (score -1):

The SF explorer has a list of all config and env variables for a given service/application. If the variable is not set using the manifest but some other means, you either need code or to rdp to the machines and export/echo the variable.

Comment: Hi can yo please elaborate on "rdp to the machines and export/echo the variable" I have set the evironment variable in applicationmanifest.xml. but it is parameterised so it shows as  this under Manifest section   <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="Code">
      <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="[ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]" />
    </EnvironmentOverrides>

Comment: I assume you can connect to the machine using RDP (remote desktop). Then on that machine start a command prompt and do something like `echo %MYENVIVARIABLE%`.

However, since it is set using environment overrides it should be visible in the list environment variables in the SF explorer. Not as `[ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]` but as the ACTUAL value. If it is `[ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]` it was not replaced correctly.